# python customtkinter UI crashes on button click

Tags: python, customtkinter

I have build a UI using customtkinter, specificly the CTkButton()

```
button_createCrawler = customtkinter.CTkButton(
    master=frame_crawlerAdd,
    text="Erstellen",
    hover=True,
    fg_color="#007b95",
    hover_color="#004f60",
    command=start_crawl
)
```

The function that gets called will start a Crawler which runs 24/7 to scrape a website. The Button itself works and calls the function, but i am unable to click anything else without crashing it. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the crash (your question is lacking code) but if you want your UI to be responsive after calling `start_crawl` you should run the content of this function in its own [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846695/13525512).